# Why simple JasmineJS and AngularJS based unit test not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write a simple test using Jasmine. The test checks if `$scope.testFlag` is set to false.

Here is my test code

```
describe('Abc Controller', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;

  //you need to indicate your module in a test
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('abcController', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
  }));


  // test 1
  it('testFlag should be set to False', function() {
    expect( $scope.testFlag).toEqual(false);
  });


});
```

But for some reason I get this error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: ConfigProvider <- Config <- collectionMetaFactory
```

Here is how my application's app.js looks like which I am including in `testRunner.html`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp') 
    app.constant('Config',
    {
        baseURL : serviceURL,
        httpTimeout : 3600000 // 1 minute
    });
    app.config(function($logProvider) {
        $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    });
```

What am I missing?

Here is controller's snippet

```
app.controller('abcController', function ($scope, $log,abcFactory, Config) {

        $scope.testFlag = false;

       // more code follows

});
```

Let me know if you need see more of the application's code (like factory, services and controller)

Comment: Can you post the controller?

Comment: @JasonM, I just posted the Controller's snippet. Let me know if you need to see more code.

Comment: This is a little out of my depth but are you injecting the constant `Config` into the `abcController`? Or do you need to? Also if you just run this code does it give you the same results or is it directly associated with Jasmine?

Comment: I tried to inject config by following this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide , but couldn't figure out how to do it in my code.  Do you have any suggestion on how to inject config?

Comment: I would test including config with scope so something like this `{$scope:$scope,Config:'test'}` and see if you get anywhere. Again this is a little out of my depth =(

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your test with `Config`, so it doesn't recognize what `Config` is and that's why you are getting this error.

A solution would be to inject `Config` into your test by using the `$provide` module. Here's how:

```
describe('Abc Controller', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;
  var Config = {
     baseURL : 'someURL',
     httpTimeout : 3600000 // 1 minute
  };

  beforeEach(function(){
        beforeEach(module('myApp'));
        module(function (_$provide_) {
            $provide = _$provide_;
            $provide.value('Config', Config);
        });
  });

  //you need to indicate your module in a test

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('abcController', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
  }));


  // test 1
  it('testFlag should be set to False', function() {
    expect( $scope.testFlag).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

This should run the tests successfully.

Hope this helps others facing a similar problem.